# How to access firebase prop's values inside a method (Vuefire)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuefire

In my component, I am doing :

```
firebase() {
  const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  return {
    race: userRef.child(userId).child('races').child(this.raceKey)
  }
},
mounted () {
  console.log(this.$firebaseRefs.race.name)
}
```

I can access the race property's values inside my component's template, but I cannot figure out how to access them inside a created hook or a method. The value is always undefined. How can I do this?

The structure for the race is:

```
race: {
 name: "the name",
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the readyCallBack function. The problem was mounted triggered before the firebase reference had actually loaded. Thank you Renaud Tarnec for the help.

```
firebase() {
  return {
    race: {
      source: userRef.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('races').child("-LMgzo_50TzlfJwCblDS"),
      asObject: true,
      cancelCallback: function () {},
      readyCallback: function() {
        console.log("Firebase race was loaded")
        this.renderMap()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because queries to Firebase Real Time Database are asynchronous, and therefore there is no guarantee that you get the result of your query in a lifecycle hook like `mounted`. In other words, the Firebase binding of your `race` object does not finish before the instance is mounted.

See the following posts for more detail and possible workaround with [readyCallback](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire#usage):

https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/issues/70 and https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/issues/69